# string split with the value of another clumn PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following data frame

```
+----+-------+
|item|   path|
+----+-------+
| -a-|  a-b-c|
| -b-|  e-b-f|
| -d-|e-b-d-h|
| -c-|  g-h-c|
+----+-------+
```

i want it to split path column with value of the item column in the same index

```
+----+--------+
|item|    path|
+----+--------+
| -b-|  [a, c]|
| -b-|  [e, f]|
| -d-|[e-b, h]|
| -c-|[g-h, b]|
+----+--------+
```

i've used this udf function

```
split_udf = udf(lambda a,b: a.split(b),T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
org = org.withColumn('crb_url', split_udf('path','item')[0])
```

it worked very well
But, i was wondering if there's another way to do it with pyspark function because i can't use in anyway the "org" to join with another dataframe or save it as a delta table
it gives me this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: The udf needs null checking (inside lambda function) in case of encountering NULL inputs. Another way is to put `split_udf` inside `if` or `case when` expressions to get only non-NULL inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.fillna("")` to fill null value to "". Like this:`org = org.fillna("").withColumn('crb_url', split_udf('path','item')[0])`